# iOS Blocks introspection

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, introspection

I would like to know two things:

**1-** Is it possible by using objective-c introspection to know the return type of a block.

For example: `int (^CountBlock)(NSArray *array)` I would like to know the type it will be returning is `int`.

The second question is:

**2-** Can I hold a reference to a generic block? What I mean with this, is basically can I do something like `id myBlock` and with this answer the first question.

**What I tried**

This kind of stuff is not possible:

```
id aBlock = ^{

    NSString * aString = @"OMG";

    return aString;
};

aBlock();
```

As the compiler sees that the `id aBlock` is not a function or a function pointer.

Comment: this might help for #1 http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/a-python-script-to-disassemble-a-block-in-lldb

Comment: @Cy-4AH the point is to know the return type of a generic block. (question 2)

Comment: Do you have a specific use case that you're trying to solve or are you only interested in what's technically possible? If it's for a specific use case then I'd suggest you re-think your solutions as introspect blocks and casting them is not a good idea. However, if you're only interested in find out what's technically possible then I encourage you to do as many crazy things you can think of!

Comment: @BenedictCohen it's actually for a possible implementation I am thinking of. But it seems a bit too weird to use it. I aim for: "Solve complex problems with simple solutions".

Comment: @JackyBoy: Have you though about, suppose you can store it generically, and you can get the signature, what do you think that allows you to do? I don't see how it allows you to use the block easily.

Comment: @newacct the point was to be able (initially) store the block in an `NSValue`. But after some considerations, I would go by another route.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but would probably be interesting to you: https://github.com/fjolnir/Tranquil/blob/master/Source/Tranquil/Runtime/TQBlockClosure.m

 It's a class that wraps arbitrary blocks and generates one that takes all object parameters, which get unboxed to whatever parameters the original block wants. (The encoding it takes is of the format <@ returnType argTypes>)

Comment: https://github.com/fjolnir/Tranquil/blob/master/Source/Tranquil/Runtime/TQBoxedObject.m#L461

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944983/2905299) talks about how to grab the signature of a block. Here's the relevant code:

```
static const char *BlockSig(id blockObj)
{
    struct Block *block = (void *)blockObj;
    struct BlockDescriptor *descriptor = block->descriptor;

    int copyDisposeFlag = 1 << 25;
    int signatureFlag = 1 << 30;

    assert(block->flags & signatureFlag);

    int index = 0;
    if(block->flags & copyDisposeFlag)
        index += 2;

    return descriptor->rest[index];
}
```

It's really not ideal, since you just get the `@encode` string of the signature, which looks like this: `@"i16@?0@8"`. I'd love to see if someone has a better approach.

2) You can definitely cast blocks to and from type `id`:

```
typedef void(^MyBlockType)(void);
id aBlock = ^ { };
((MyBlockType)aBlock)();
```

Of course, if you cast to the wrong block type, you'll end up with undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't know the original signature of the block, so I cannot typecast it.

Comment: Can you create a class that stores both a block and some representation of the signature so that you can invoke the block correctly?

Comment: That would be something I didn't think of, but yes it would be possible to do that.

Comment: @godel9: "Can you create a class that stores both a block and some representation of the signature so that you can invoke the block correctly?" Invoking a function with a signature that is known only at runtime, cannot be portably done in C, because it requires knowing the calling convention of the particular architecture, and using assembly to put the arguments in the right places in the registers and stack.

Comment: @newacct You're absolutely right. I was thinking there was just a handful of block types that were known at compile-time, but there's nothing in the question to back up that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem for number 2 is that blocks are named as part of the type definition, e.g.

```
void (^blockName)(void) = ^{};
```

A workaround is to define a generic block type:

```
typedef void(^BlockType)(void);
BlockType myBlock = ^{};
myBlock();
```

edit: pointed out by @neilco, a much simpler way using dispatch block types (which return nothing and accept no arguments):

```
dispatch_block_t myBlock = ^{};
myBlock();
```

Comment: There's already a built-in block type with that signature. It's called `dispatch_block_t`.

Comment: So you suggest casting the block type to a different (incorrect for that block) block type?

Comment: @newacct no this was just an example of a way to have a "type" for a block, i didn't try to match the typdef to either of the given examples

Comment: right but this seems strictly worse than using `id` or `NSObject *`, both of which would be at least correct

Comment: I misunderstood a bit and thought OP knew the block type, so for that case this is definitely not worse than using id, but yes casting any block to some random block type is not a good idea