# Check Objective-C block class

Tags: objective-c, block

I've watched [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048305/checking-objective-c-block-type), but didn't found a solution.

I have a timer

```
self.checklinkTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                           target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(doWithHandler:)
                                                         userInfo:nil
                                                          repeats:YES];
```

and method

```
-(void) doWithHandler:(void (^)(BOOL isValid))handler
{
    handler(isSessionValid);
}
```

and other method where i use boolean value from `doWithHandler` method.

In `doWithHandler` i need to check if handler is NSTimer class and in that case, not do `handler(isSessionValid)` .

I tried `if ( ! [(id)handler isKindOfClass:[NSTimer class]] )` or `@try @catch` but this don't work this way.

**Question**: how can i check block class?

Comment: "but this don't work this way": Please explain.

Comment: Why would that parameter ever be anything other than a `NSTimer`?

Comment: Docs: "The timer passes itself as the argument, thus the method would adopt the following pattern:
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer".

Comment: Blocks are implemented as NSBlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can don something like that instead of your original idea for achieving the same behaviour:

```
self.checklinkTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

---

then you have:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self doWithHandler:nil];
}
```

---

where

```
- (void)doWithHandler:(void (^)(BOOL isValid))handler {
    if (handler) handler(isSessionValid); // I don't know where `isSessionValid` comes from...
}
```